# max fd limit on windows

Tags: windows, jmeter, operating-system, file-descriptor

i have an issue during a load test.
i am trying to open 100k concurrent users, each user gets a thread and opens a java `SockJsClient` object for the connection.
the problem occurs when i am reaching more than 32k connections. the test is not indicating any problem with new threads and i see 50k open threads. but on the service side i see only 32.2k open connections.

it is not a service issue bacause i can open this amount from multiple machines combined.

there is no resouce issue on my machine as i have 128GB of RAM and the used memory barely reaches 20% as well as the CPU.
i am afraid there is some OS limitation on the number of open fd.
the problem is that i run on windows 10 and can not find any documantation of open files limit per system or per proccess.
is there anything i can do to increase the limit or even check what the limit is?

Comment: Are those connections using IPv4? (FWIW, I'm impressed that you're able to get that many connection going without running into issues.)

Comment: yes, the connections using IPv4

Comment: Is it possible that you are running out of available ports? - a port is 16 bits, maybe it's limited to the signed range of that, it would fit the symptom you describe, but I admit I am just guessing here.

Comment: is there a way to configue windows to use IPv6?

Comment: It's enabled by default, but you have to write the socket code accordingly, both in the client and in the server.

Comment: i am not writing the low level sockets code like you are describing i am using spring objects.

Comment: Windows has [65.535 ports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38141340/52598) of  which you can (kind of) freely use ports above 1024. IPv6 does not change that. If you need 100k simultanious connections, you need (at least) two machines.

Comment: thanks, seems like exactly the issue, but somehow i was able to use just half of that amount

Comment: @Dev93 - Yes and that doesn't match with how I interpreted things. I would have assumed you could only use 16k ports. Doing a netstat on your server should at least tell you the port rang being used. I'm curious ;). [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/troubleshoot-tcpip-port-exhaust) is also a good read