# Why docker uses port numbers from 32768-65535?

Tags: docker, containers

Being new to Docker, I have a basic question on why Docker uses the port numbers ranging from 32768 to 65535 ?

Why is that particular range selection ? Are other ports not useful ?

Can someone help me in understanding this better..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The port numbers in the range from 0 to 1023 are the system ports. These are used for standard, well-known network services. They are also restricted, so only the super user is able to bind to one of these.

Next ranges of ports, especially under 10000, are still usually a standard ports of some services, but they are not restricted. Some common examples are 8080 (HTTP alternative), 8443 (HTTPS alternative) or 1099 (Java RMI registry). See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) for more examples.

Range of 32768 to 65535 is quite safe to just get a random one and use, because they are not used widely.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: These ports were once defined for being not to be reserved for some special use like 80 or 443.

Long anwser: [Best TCP port number range for internal applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476987/best-tcp-port-number-range-for-internal-applications)