# sending data over TCP in android

Tags: android

hi i was trying to connect My Android app to send data to my PC.
i can get the data from PC to my android but i cant send data to my pc with android 
it is my code :

```
try 
{                   
    clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.1.90",8080);
    OutputStream out = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
    output.println("Hello Android!");
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    String st = input.readLine();
    clientSocket.close();
    store.add("send it");                   
} 
catch (UnknownHostException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    store.add(e.toString());
    //error_view.setText(e.toString());
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    store.add(e.toString());
    //error_view.setText(e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like:

```
  clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.1.90", 8888);
  DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
  dataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
  dataOutputStream.writeUTF(textOut.getText().toString());
```

For more view:

- [Simple communication using java.net.Socket](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/01/simple-communication-using.html)
- [android tcp/ip socket won't send data to computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131316/android-tcp-ip-socket-wont-send-data-to-computer)

Comment: whats difference between my Code and Your Code Suggestion  ?