# NetBeans Server(On PC) Client(On Android)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to send a string from real android device(client) to pc(server) where server is running on Netbeans 8.0 and device is connected to pc over wifi(using pc wifi hotspot by connectify).
Server code:

```
try {

            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // accept the client connection
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); // get the client message
            message = bufferedReader.readLine();

            System.out.println(message);
            inputStreamReader.close();
            clientSocket.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
        }
```

and the client code:

```
try{
            client = new Socket("192.168.207.1", 4444); 
            printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            printwriter.write("SENTTTTTTTTT");
            printwriter.flush();
            printwriter.close();
            client.close(); 

    } catch (Exception e) {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception-->"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
```

I have tested (Using PING app) that the IP is reachable.
But when I ran app on device it gives Exception-->null.
But when I tested server & client both on pc as an JAVA SE app it works fine.
But it is not working on android device.

Comment: I have been using this to send a message from Android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131316/android-tcp-ip-socket-wont-send-data-to-computer/20131985#20131985

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be an exception if a network operation is executed on the main thread in Android

Make sure you are not doing networking operations on the main thread in Android.

That is do all the same in a separate thread.

Comment: True, but how does that answer the question?

Comment: There will be an exception if a network operation is executed on the main thread in Android

Comment: please help me by providing me a full example tutorial.

Comment: @Subhadeep did you try and follow the link from my comment?

Comment: I've tried that.Server is showing "null".but the server works fine with other java SE clients on PC.@ cYrixmorten